# Unable to connect to EC2 instance with error, Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh, permission-denied

I am trying to connect to ec2 instance created and I am using the correct pem file but getting permission denied error. I am attaching the stack, please help

```
OpenSSH_7.5p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2o  27 Mar 2018
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 13: Deprecated option "useroaming"
debug1: Connecting to ec2-3-87-194-41.compute-1.amazonaws.com [3.87.194.41] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file git.pem type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file git.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.5
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.0
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.0 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to ec2-3-87-194-41.compute-1.amazonaws.com:22 as 'ec2-user'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: zlib@openssh.com
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: zlib@openssh.com
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:zGgdD+4VYOiiGb6LDf12e/Zhd4DjIN9qqSQtXtm/I8o
debug1: Host 'ec2-3-87-194-41.compute-1.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_fetch_identitylist: agent refused operation
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: git.pem
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with user `root`?

Sometimes, depends by the AMI you choose, you must connect with a different username (like `ubuntu`, for example).

When you try to login with root, the server replies to you saying which user you need to use.

```
Please login as the user "ubuntu" rather than the user "root".
```

Try with this

```
ssh root@ec2-3-87-194-41.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```